# can we able to achieve the row level security in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there any possibility to achieve the row-level security in SSRS(Reporting Tool) based on the Active Directory credentials.

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-data-security-feature-rls-row-level-security-and-gdpr/

In the above, the RLS is managed completely in SQL server but my requirement is to handle RLS in SSRS.

The SSRS report should show the data based on user login.

Comment: You've tagged SSRS 2008 (which is completely out of support) and 2012 here. Neither of these DBMS support RLS; which was introducted in 2016. Either way, for actual RLS, the SQL Server Data Engine would still handle it, as you would have the report use the user's AD credentials to run the report.

Comment: Thanks for the response Larnu, can you please elaborate on how to use the AD credentials in SSRS reports.

Comment: That totally depends on  the version of SSRS and/or the type of data source your report uses; SSRS 2008 and SSRS 2012 are quite different and you've tagged both.

Comment: You can add the user account as a parameter in the query for the report. The query will return the data based on the user.

Answer (score 1):

Create an [Internal Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-change-or-delete-a-report-parameter-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) with a default of `User!UserID` (see [built-in User Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-built-in-globals-and-users-references-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017)).  Then use that parameter in your Datasets.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to maintain row level security as long as the permissions info maintained in reporting database with active directory accounts:

In my case i'm applying row level security with following steps, hope same would work for you:

1. Create additional parameter (@User), it always hidden parameter
2. Set `@User` default value with expression `=Replace(User!UserID, "DomainName\", "")`
3. Filter other parameters or report with `@User` parameter via *Datasets Properties -> query*

Example Report query:

```
select * 
from ReportView 
where entity in (select entity from PermissionView where UserID = @User)
```

Comment: It _must_ be an Internal parameter, not a hidden parameter.  A user can provide the value for a hidden parameter.

Comment: Thanks for notifying that @DavidBrowne, do you mean like this `http://localhost/reports/ReportName?User="User.name"`. Fortunately, when i tried the hidden parameter doesn't accept in this method.