# How we can implement RLS in SSRS when using Snowflake as a data source

Tags: reporting-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ssrs-2012

I am using snowflake as a data source and created many SSRS reports. I want to implement row level security on data, so that if a manager opening a SSRS report he can see data related to employee who is working under him.

Comment: you could look at passing userid as a parameter and return records only to rows where this user is the manager. Let SQL handle this

Comment: In our case we have more than 1000 manager and all data source we are using Snowflake, I checked it within snowflake RLS we can do but in that we have to create 1000 users and then put RLS on the table based upon the users and when ever manager is opening the SSRS it will ask the users credential. But I'm looking for only one user credential for all the manager and RLS as well.

Comment: Given a row of data in snowflake.. how do you determine who has access to it? Is it managed by the database? If so, there must be a mechanism to say which user has access to which row.. so in case of SSRS, you just pass in the logged in user ID as the parameter to the DB and let the DB handle it.. UNless I have misunderstood your requirement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the RLS in snowflake and when laoding the SSRS you can filter by the user account matching that RLS table

something similar to what has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479135/can-we-able-to-achieve-the-row-level-security-in-ssrs)